# How to assign string argv[] to an int array in C?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm begginer in writing stackoverflow questions, so if i have mistake, please tell me.

how to assign argv datas in to an int array like this:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int list[];

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; argv[i][i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        list[i] = argv[i];
    }
```

this script makes error in line 10
error message:

```
selection.c:10:17: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'string' (aka 'char *') [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
        list[i] = argv[i];
```

i tried this script and i expect it works and assign without error

Comment: Try this: `list[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);`

Comment: `int list[];` has no size. And `argv[i][i]` is nonsense.

Comment: Define a size for `list`. Check that `argc` won't overflow that size. Then perhaps `for (int i = 1; argv[i] != NULL; i++) list[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);`. But it's more idiomatic to use `argc` to iterate.

Comment: @CraigEstey atoi causes undefined behaviour, recommend strtol instead.

Comment: @Fredrik `atoi` is the simple choice. `strtol` might be better [particularly for parsing input from `fgets`]. But, how does `atoi` cause UB [and `strtol` does not]?

Comment: @CraigEstey if the number is to large to fit into an int atoi causes UB while strtol will not. atoi is wortless in that regard as you will have to manually check the string first to determine if the number will fit

Comment: @Fredrik That's overflow but I don't think it's UB. For that matter, we could say the same thing for `strtol` [on 32 bit systems] and recommend we always use `strtoll`. But, `atoi` for `argv` conversion is common. The goal here is to get things working for OP and then explore edge cases. For example, `int list[];` (as others have mentioned) is bad. A function scoped VLA `int list[argc - 1];` and proper loop termination are more pressing issues here. `strtol` (or `atol`) would be the immediate choice if we had `long list[argc - 1];`

Comment: Agreed that a more rigorous approach should be used for all forms of user input. But the use of `atoi` is a distraction at the level of which the question is asked. It will get them going, one step at a time.

Comment: No strtol sets errno to defined error codes when values are to large, it does not have any UB. atoi is define by the standard to be UB when that happens making the function worthless, and should in my opinion be removed as they did with gets. But yes in OPs case this discussion may not be the right place.

Comment: @Fredrik the damage that can be caused by `gets()` is a totally different order. With `atoi()` it is the *value* that may be undefined on overflow. The Standard coyly says 'undefined' but that doesn't mean the memory bounds of the `int` are broken. To some extent, the user can check that the result is within expected bounds, but with `gets()` string overflow there may not be that opportunity.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes gets is another beast entirely. C has a lot of UB and I would like an effort to remove all possibilities of UB in all standard library functions. UB in C wouldn't go away but we would atleast have a standard library with 0

Comment: Wait, what do you mean, "dates." Like 2024-02-26? What is the actual purpose of the programme?

Answer (score 0):

The crux of your issue (needing to convert input strings into integers) is quite evident in the compiler warning you received, as well as noted in the good comments.  And with the incomplete code example, determining what you were getting for output makes things a bit nebulous.

But being nebulous allows for some artistic license to attempt to provide you with a possible path.  First off, I refactored your code to include a "printf" statement to provide a simplified visual debugging of what happens when the compiled code is run.

```
int list[];

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; argv[i][i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        list[i] = argv[i];
        printf("list %d: %d\n", i, list[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Testing this code with some simple integer input parameters yielded the following terminal output.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/IntArray/bin/Release$ ./IntArray 11 22 33 44 55 66
list 1: -2057661520
```

With that, and reviewing the back and forth of utilizing the "atoi" or "strtol", I opted to provide the following refactored version to point out one possible avenue to accept integer parameters and store them in an integer array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char * string;              /* Do not have CS50 tools installed - this is a workaround  */

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int lst[argc - 1];                                  /* Define integer list size here        */

    printf("First argument (argv[0]): %s\n", argv[0]);  /* This will be the program name        */

    for (int i = 0; i < (argc - 1); i++)                /* Convert and store integer parms      */
        lst[i] = atoi(argv[i + 1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < (argc - 1); i++)                /* Test output of parameters            */
        printf("Argument %2d: %d\n", i + 1, lst[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

With this refactoring, I opted for using the "atoi" function, as again I utilized some artistic license to illustrate a method of converting character array input into integers.  I will let you review all of the good comments to determine which function best suits your needs.  Following are some key points that may or may not be obvious.

- The very first argument passed in when the program is called is the program name.
- Subsequently, each additional parameter passed in will be a character array (a string).
- The size of the array will be such that it can hold all of the arguments other than the program name.

Following some sample output at the terminal.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/IntArray/bin/Release$ ./IntArray 11 22 33 44 55 66
First argument (argv[0]): ./IntArray
Argument  1: 11
Argument  2: 22
Argument  3: 33
Argument  4: 44
Argument  5: 55
Argument  6: 66
```

Now, this refactored code would benefit from some additional validation to ensure integers were being passed as parameters, but I will leave that to you.  Hopefully, this gives you food for thought.

Also, you may want to delve some more into available "C" tutorial literature.

Answer (score -1):

In cs50 `string` is

```
        typedef char* string;
```

In `main`

```
    int list[];
```

is not defined. You must have a size in order to declare an array of `int`. There is a thing called **VLA**  **V**ariable-**l**ength **a**rray that enable things like this one, but is an extension. It is seen mostly in students programs, almost never in production code. Consult your instructor or company before using such things.

Anyway this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef char* string;

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
int list[argc-1];
for (int i = 1; argv[i][i] != '\0'; i++)
        list[i] = argv[i];
}
```

since `argc` is already known at run-time in this point of the code. In Microsoft compiler expect errors like

```
(6): error C2057: expected constant expression
(6): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of 
(6): error C2133: 'list': unknown size
```

#### why `error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion`?

`argv` is `char*[]`, `list` is `int[]` and this is it: there is no such implicit conversion: `argv` is an array of pointers. As an example, you can write

```
    double my_d = 42.42;
    int    my_i = my_d;
    printf("double is %f, int is %d\n", my_d, my_i);
```

should print

```
double is 42.420000, int is 42
```

The compiler will complain about possible data loss --- sure `0.42` will vanish --- but there is an implicit conversion from `double` to `int`.

#### about the provided code

Note that in

```
    for (int i = 1; argv[i][i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        list[i] = argv[i];
    }
```

- the braces are optional and are adding nothing.
- `'\0'` is exactly `0`: prefer the simple `0` over using 4 symbols for the same use and having to worry about missing a quote.
- `argv[i][i]` is a `char`, `argv[argc]` is a `NULL` pointer to it can be compared to `0`, but since you already know `argc` why not just use its value to exit the loop?

#### Example 1

For this `p.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++)
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n",i,argv[i]);
}
```

we get

```
SO> p Stack Overflow
argv[1] = Stack
argv[2] = Overflow

SO>
```

#### Example 2

This one uses a dynamic list and a static one (limiting the arguments to the list size).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // alloc `list` with required size
    printf("using dynamic list\n");
    int* list = malloc(argc * sizeof(int));
    if (list == NULL) return -1;  // malloc failed
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        list[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
        printf(
            "argv[%d] = %s, list[%d] = %d\n", i, argv[i], i,
            list[i]);
    }
    free(list);  // no more use for list

    printf("\nusing static list\n");
    int ls[12];
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        ls[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
        printf(
            "argv[%d] = %s, list[%d] = %d\n", i, argv[i], i,
            ls[i]);
        if (i >= argc - 1) return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
SO> p Stack Overflow 42 -42 0
using dynamic list
argv[1] = Stack, list[1] = 0
argv[2] = Overflow, list[2] = 0
argv[3] = 42, list[3] = 42
argv[4] = -42, list[4] = -42
argv[5] = 0, list[5] = 0

using static list
argv[1] = Stack, list[1] = 0
argv[2] = Overflow, list[2] = 0
argv[3] = 42, list[3] = 42
argv[4] = -42, list[4] = -42
argv[5] = 0, list[5] = 0

SO>
```

Note that the conversion functions return `0` for a string and `0` for a zero, so if you need to know if zero is zero you need to parse the string letters...

Comment: "but is an extension" No it is not, it is a mandatory feature (again) as per C23.

Comment: "'\0' is exactly 0: prefer the simple 0 over using 4 symbols for the same use" This is plain misguided and bad advise - always write self-documenting code. `'\0'` is exactly that, a de facto industry standard for null termination. Whereas `0` is just a magic number that can mean anything in numerous contexts.

Comment: "the braces are optional and are adding nothing" Mandatory braces no matter how many lines that are inside the compound is a common style used many professional settings. To dismiss it is to sign up to become author for the next "Apple goto fail" bug.

Comment: As for `atoi` (family), it is one of those functions that should never be used for any purpose due to the bad error handling. The `strtol` (family) should be used instead, it is equivalent but safer.

Comment: Of course you won't find anything in standard C about it, all the standard says is that it's an octal escape sequence with value zero. Hence "de facto industry standard for null termination". This is known as self-documenting code and every C programmer knows of this convention since it is taught everywhere from ancient K&R until programming books and classes of today - 50 years of programming conventions. Functionality-wise it is the same thing as `0`, of course. Just like a line with no comments has the same function as the same one with comments.

Comment: You are mixing up null pointers and null termination now. These are two different and completely unrelated things that happen to be named "null-something"... This too is common knowledge.

Comment: `stddef.h` (not "strdef.h") has nothing to do with strings what-so-ever, so I don't understand what you are even on about or why you were hoping to find any `'\0'` there. As for the internals of standard libs, they are usually written in peculiar internal manners and we need not worry about that. But if you insist, maybe peek into the actual implementation of something actually dealing with strings - `string.h` comes to mind: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/lib/string.c. As you can see it has `'\0'` all over the place, as it was written by C programmers.

Comment: Libc's not Linux...

Comment: You are starting to sound like a broken record now. Since you evidently don't know the difference between null pointers and null termination, do let me explain why `0` is indeed "just a magic number that can mean anything in numerous contexts". Apart from obviously being an integer with value zero, as well as possible to use as a null termination sentinel in C strings, it is also a null pointer constant which can indeed be used to turn a pointer into a null pointer. But it was also C's only boolean `false` type all the way to C23. And so on.

Comment: Whereas the octal escape sequence version is only ever used to mean a null terminator.

Comment: I have much to learn with you guys! I answered the question, with arguments, two examples and output, but my answer is marked as not useful in minutes. Would it be wrong? I will try to improve :)